# WebInvoke POST stops service from installing

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I'm TOTALLY new at c#.  ***SORRY***

I'm trying to create a WCF Rest service to get and put files on a web server.  The following operation works great:

```
         [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetMediaFile?shopNumber={shopNumber}&fileName={fileName}")]
    Stream GetMediaFile(string shopNumber, string fileName);
```

Everything works as expected until I add the following operation

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat =        WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "PutMediaFile?shopNumber={shopNumber}&fileName={fileName}")]
    string PutMediaFile(string shopNumber, string fileName, Stream mediaFile);
```

I'm installing the service by clicking on the green arrow that launches the tool that installs the service.  I need to do this to test it from my IOS device.

The problem is that once I add the POST method, I get the following error during the service install:

```
 "Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata"
```

followed by a more indepth explanation:

```
 "Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost/MpiPhotoStore/PhotoStoreService.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost/MpiPhotoStore/PhotoStoreService.svc    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost/MpiPhotoStore/PhotoStoreService.svc'.    There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/MpiPhotoStore/PhotoStoreService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.    The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost/MpiPhotoStore/PhotoStoreService.svc    There was an error downloading 'http://localhost/MpiPhotoStore/PhotoStoreService.svc'.    The request failed with the error message:--<HTML><HEAD><STYLE type="text/css">#content{ FONT-SIZE: 0.7em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 30px}BODY{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white}P{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana}PRE{BORDER-RIGHT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BORDER-TOP: #f0f0e0 1px solid; MARGIN-TOP: -5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 5px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #f0f0e0 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e5e5cc}.heading1{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 26px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; MARGIN-LEFT: -30px; WIDTH: 100%; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-TOP: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #003366}.intro{MARGIN-LEFT: -15px}</STYLE><TITLE>Service</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><DIV id="content"><P class="heading1">Service</P><BR/><P class="intro">The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.</P></DIV></BODY></HTML>--."
```

Like I said, I have a 2 GET operation and 1 DELETE operation that all work fine.

Here is my Web.Config

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>

 <appSettings>
 <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
 <add key="RootFilePath" value="\\OMMACDEV02VM1\Images"/>
 </appSettings>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
 <protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding"/>
 </protocolMapping>
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

I've read about mex endpoints but I'm really only looking at JSON right now.  The Web.Config is working fine for every other method.

HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the web.config file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
<appSettings>
 <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
<add key="RootFilePath" value="\\OMMACDEV02VM1\Images"/>
</appSettings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MpiPhotoStore.PhotoStore" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MpiPhotoStore.IPhotoStoreService" behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```